# Basic onclick javascript jquery code to Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm used to jquery and I'm rewriting my code to Vue. Need a little help with this basic onclick event.

Original html:

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="right-nav" onclick="closeRightNav();"></div>

    <i onclick="openRightNav();"></i>

</div>
```

Original javascript:

```
function openRightNav() {
    $("#right-nav").width("100%");
}

function closeRightNav() {
    $("#right-nav").width("0");
}
```

This is where I'm currently at:

New html:

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="right-nav" @click="closeRightNav"></div>

    <i @click="openRightNav"></i>

</div>
```

New javascript using Vue:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',

    data: {
        width: '100%'
    },

    methods: {
        openRightNav() {
            $("#right-nav").width("100%"); // not sure how to write this part in Vue?
        }
    }
});
```

How do I write this correctly in Vue?

Comment: Which part specifically isn't working for you?

Comment: I'm rewriting my jquery code to Vue so it's data centric (Vue) instead of DOM centric (jquery).

Answer (score 2):

Ok. You can approach this from multiple angles. I like to use v-show or v-if directives like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="rightOpen" id="right-div" style="width:100%">Right Div</div>
    <a @click="rightOpen = ! rightOpen">Toggle</a> // this will actually toggle right sidebar open and close
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        rightOpen: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now you could use v-show instead of v-if difference is v-show element will  be rendered on the page but not shown and v-if will not render element.

You could also use v-class like so

```
...
<div :class="{ 'someClass': !rightOpen,'sidebar-opened': rightOpen}" id="right-div">Right Div</div>
....
```

In this example someClass will be the one loaded when component is rendered, lets say width: 0 will be in that class. sidebar-opened class should contain width: 100%. Everything else stays the same from previous example.

Comment: ^  This is how I would be doing it.

Answer (score 1):

in `openRightNav` you change your data and don't manipulate the DOM directly. Just say in your method: `this.width = 100`.

in your html then you need to bind your `width` attribute like this:

`<div id="right-nav" @click="closeRightNav" v-bind:style="{'width': width + '%'}"></div>`

don't forget to set your default value for `width` to 0.

in `closeRightNav` you would only write: `this.width = 0`

Comment: Is it ok to have multiple var a1 = new Vue({ el: '#main' }); var a2 = new Vue({ el: '#main' }); var a3 = new Vue({ el: '#main' }); etc. targeting the same element?

Comment: I wouldn't do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yousef Kama here's how I ended up doing it:

New html:

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="right-nav" @click="closeRightNav" v-bind:style="{'width': width + '%'}"></div>

    <i @click="openRightNav"></i>

</div>
```

New Vue javascript:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',

    data: {
        width: 0
    },

    methods: {
        openRightNav() {
            this.width = 100;
        },

        closeRightNav() {
            this.width = 0;
        }
    }
});
```